# working with ratios and RMS to find variables

Tags: homework, gas-laws

**question**
consider separate 1.0L samples of helium and $UF_6$ both at 1.00atm and containing the same number of moles. what will the ratio of the separate temperature need to be in order to have the same root-mean-square speed?

**my steps**
So i set up an equation
$\sqrt{\frac{3(8.314T)}{0.004}}$=$\sqrt{\frac{3(8.314T)}{0.352008}}$
but i soon realized that that would be impossible
and that is where i got stuck

Comment: Well, obviously the temperatures are not going to be the same. They asked for a ratio of temperatures. So you can't denote both temperatures by the same symbol $T$. If you let the temperature of helium be $T_1$ and the temperature of UF6 be $T_2$, then you need to find $T_1:T_2$.

Comment: (1) Setup equation using variables and cancel out all common stuff, solve for the needed variable, then plug in the numbers. (2) How did you get 0.004 for the mass of Helium?!?

Comment: ok but i was wondering if you can provide some helpful hints rather than telling me to cancel out the variables, thats kind of obvious. Can you give me a booster step?

Comment: @MaxW I think OP is taking mass in kg.

Comment: John - Look at orthocresol's comment. The whole point is that if you setup the problem using letters for variables a whole bunch of the variables cancel and you're left with a very simple relationship. By just trying to plug numbers into some formula I don't think you really understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As I said solve using variables first and simplify as much as you can, then plug in the numbers. From the [Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution):

$v_p = \sqrt{\frac{2RT}{M}}$

$v_{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}v_p$

where:

- $v_p$ most probably velocity
- $v_{rms}$ rms velocity
- R universal gas constant
- T temperature
- M molecular mass

so let:

- $v_{p,He}$ - most probably velocity for He
- $v_{p,U}$ - most probably velocity for $\ce{UF6}$
- $v_{rms,He}$ - rms velocity for He
- $v_{rms,U}$ - rms probably velocity for $\ce{UF6}$

we're given:
 $v_{rms,He} = v_{rms,U}$

but
 $v_{rms,He} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}v_{p,He}$
and 
$v_{rms,U} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}v_{p,U}$
so:
$\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}v_{p,He} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}v_{p,U}$

which can be simplified to: 
$v_{p,He} = v_{p,U}$

Now substituting from the Maxwell-Boltzmann equation for $v_p$ for both He and $\ce{UF6}$ we have:

$\sqrt{\frac{2RT_{He}}{M_{He}} } =  \sqrt{\frac{2RT_U}{M_U}}$

simplying
$\frac{T_{He}}{M_{He}} = \frac{T_{U}}{M_{U}}$

rearranging:
$\frac{T_{U}}{T_{He}} = \frac{M_{U}}{M_{He}} = \frac{352.02}{4.003} = 87.94$

Superfluous information is that $\ce{UF6}$ decomposes about $1800^o \text{ K}$ and is a solid below about $330^o \text{ K}$. Helium liquefies about $4.2^o \text{ K}$. So this only works if Helium is in range $4.2^o \text{ K}$ to $18.4^o \text{ K}$ which would mean that the uranium hexfluoride is between $369^o \text{ K}$ to $1800^o \text{ K}$.